# Spring Cloud Stream with autoscaling subscribers will it process the same message using cloud pubsub binder?

Tags: spring, stream, cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I have two services on Google Appengine that autoscale with increased load from 2 - 20 instances. I just added spring cloud stream and the pubsub binder to publish messages that a communication service subscribes to. It seems to work so far but I have been questioned as to what would happen when the subscriber autoscales. Is there a chance to pull the same message from the queue? I saw under the properties in the docs 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/#_configuration_options
It shows instance count and instance index. I am not sure how to even set these when the instances are ephemeral and read from the same external configs.  If anyone has ran into this issue please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

There is no something like *queue* in the Google Cloud Pub/Sub. There is a topic and subscriptions. So, if all your subscribers use the same subscription (consumer group in terms of SCSt), only exactly one instance is going to get a message from the topic.

See more info in the Reference Manual: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gcp/1.1.0.RELEASE/multi/multi__spring_cloud_stream.html#_consumer_destination_configuration